# TLS 1.2 Error With C# .Net : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, webclient, tls1.2

I have a c# .net site and my site do request to bank for payment system. Everything was good about 3-4 days ago, But Now I cant request to bank server from my server. I get this error: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." when I try request to bank.

**I am getting this error when I request it from .net c# code.**

```
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
```

**Here is my code;**

```
    public string Send(string request)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    try
    {
        string postData = "";
        string responseData = "";
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9");

        postData = "https://xxxxxxxxx.aspx?data=[DATA]";
        postData = postData.Replace("[DATA]", request);
        HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postData);
        webReq.Timeout = 60000;
        webReq.KeepAlive = false;
        webReq.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse webResp = webReq.GetResponse();
        Stream respStream = webResp.GetResponseStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
        int len = 0, r = 1;
        while (r > 0)
        {
            r = respStream.Read(buffer, len, 10000 - len);
            len += r;
        }
        respStream.Close();
        responseData = encoding.GetString(buffer, 0, len).Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
        return responseData;
    }
    catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**I am getting this error When I try from IE 11.**

[image]
[image]

**When I try IE 11, EventViewer is showing an error.**

```
A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 40.
```

**But There is an interesting thing here, Chrome and Firefox can go same adress.**

[image]

- OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

  - All Certificates installed.
  - TLS settings configured for POODLE.(From: http://wiki.maestropanel.com/windows-server-ssl-tls-yapilandirmasi/)
  - IIS Version: 8.5
  - .Net Version: 4.5

Thanks for help!

Comment: did anything change on your servers or in your application shortly before the failures started? were any windows updates applied? are your sure the problem isn't on the bank's side?

Comment: I am sure the problem is not to bank's side. If problem is to bank's side, How to work success chrome and firefox. I tall bank's support and ms14-066 update last mounth left. My last success transaction date is 5 Dec.

Comment: if you carried out an update last month, and it has been a month since the last successful transaction, then you might want to roll back the update to a previous version and see if that works.

Comment: I've done some googling and it looks like ms14-066 was a botched patch that broke some Schannel functionality. uninstall the update.

Comment: Bank carried out an update last mount, and I can't want to roll back it. How can I exceed this problem and what is the problem. And where is the problem, where can I should look?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the bank website changed its SSL certificate, or otherwise changed its security configuration, such that when your client sends the list of cipher_suites values that it is able to accept in its initial SSL handshaking/negotiation "Client Hello" message, there is no match with what the bank is (now) willing to support.

Chrome and Firefox (evidently) have their own sets of cipher_suites values that are independent of your operating system's configured values, which is why they are still working when Internet Explorer is not.

I'd suggest downloading [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226), and using it to run a trace on the SSL negotiation that occurs when you try and fail to establish an SSL connection to the bank website (in your C# app or in Internet Explorer).  Then, run another trace on what happens when the SSL negotiation succeeds (in Firefox or Chrome).

Hopefully, you'll see some difference between the two Client Hello messages that'll allow you to pinpoint what about the failing SSL negotiation is causing it to fail.  Then you should be able to make configuration changes to Windows that will allow it to succeed.  [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) is a great tool to use for this (even for client PCs, despite the "IIS" name).

The following two Windows registry keys govern the cipher_suites values that your PC will use:

- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002
- HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010002

Here's a full writeup of how I solved a very similar problem to yours earlier today: http://blog.jonschneider.com/2016/08/fix-ssl-handshaking-error-in-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem after installing TLS1.2 on the server; the solution was to add the following line of code in  Application_Start() function in case of web applications or in the Main method in Program.cs file in case of Windows applications as follows:

Web applications:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //Add this line
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        //End
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
```

Windows Applications:

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //Add this line
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        //End
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Default());
    }
```